# How to let the tableview control fit the entire screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I add a TableView to a new Single View Application. The exercise requires me to allow the TableView control to fit the entire screen. But I can't find any function to do this. Should I adjust the parameters in the Table View in Size Inspector?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Table View **Control**"? Do you simply need the table view itself to fill the entire screen?

Comment: Use constraints.

Comment: @Eilon I think so.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, I'm a new switf learner. I can't find the constrains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should learn auto-layout and constraints as they're an extremely important part of building up layout in `UIKit`.
For now, this is how you set your table view (or essentially any view) to fill the screen:

1. Select your table view
2. Click on the **Add New Constraint** button at the bottom right of your storyboard.
3. Set `0` for top, bottom, left and right.

That will add 4 constraints that will stretch your table view to fill up all the space available in the screen's safe area.

[image: e.g.]